# requestAnimationFrame() javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating a fps game using javascript, and I am running into some problems with requestAnimationFrame().

so this is the snippet of my code I think matters:

```
var animate=window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
            function(callback){
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000/60);
            };

function reset (){
    allFood=[];
    animationId=[];
    init();
}

var step  = function (){
    animationId.push(animate (step));
    update ();
    render ();
}

function update (){
    if (play && !gameOver){
        for (var i=0; i<allFood.length; i++){
            allFood[i].update();
        }
        for(var i=0; i<allFood.length; i++){
            if(allFood[i].y>HEIGHT) allFood.splice(i, 1);
        }
        player.update();
        MAX_FOOD_LENGTH=player.width*0.8;
        MIN_FOOD_LENGTH = player.width * 0.05;
    }
    else if(!gameOver){
        mainMenu.update();
    }

}

function render (){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    context.fillStyle = backgroundColor;
    context.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    if(play || gameOver){
        for (var i=0; i<allFood.length; i++){
            allFood[i].render();
        }
        player.render();
        context.font ="40px serif";
        context.strokeText(score, WIDTH-200, 100);
    }
    else if(!gameOver){
        mainMenu.render();
    }
    animationId.shift();
}
```

So the problem is that when I first open the game it runs at 60 fps which works (I tested this out using getTime() function and a counter), but after its gameover and I call the reset function and the user clicks play again it starts running at higher fps(first at 110 fps, and then next time at 200...), which messes with the code. Is there something I have to reset involving my animate function. I tried putting everything in my step function inside of a setTimeout () with a 60 fps rate suggested by a user to control fps but it still didn't work and the fps kept on increasing everytime I pressed replay.

Comment: Please post how you calculate the fps. It's just an error in your calculation, it doesn't run at more than 60fps. Or possiby that you have multiple game loops running at the same time.

Comment: Clearing the array with the `animationIds` will not unschedule your callback. You'll have to call `cancelAnimationFrame`/`clearTimeout` explicitly in your `reset` function.

Comment: You might want to add what `animate`, `update` and `render` in this post. Other than that, we can't help you.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame() doesn't run at a fixed rate... you should be taking the time into account in your "update()" and "render()" method to decide how much of an update to apply (also, you should be scheduling the next frame after your current frame completed, not before). However, 200fps seems bogus.

Comment: I updated my code with the two methods...but I'm not sure how much insight that will give. Also to answer Nette question, I don't explicitly calculate fps because I assumed that requestAnimationFram() automatically sets fps, usually at 60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely running multiple game loops.
The solution would be to run the loop once and simply keep a flag which determines if anything should be rendered or updated.

```
var isAlive = true;
var step  = function (){
    animate(step);
    if(isAlive) {
        update ();
        render ();
    }
}
step();
```

Alternatively clear all animation frames from your stack at reset:

```
function reset (){
    allFood=[];
    for(var i = 0; i < animationId.length; i++) {
        cancelAnimationFrame(animationId[i]);
    }
    animationId = [];
    init();
}
```

However then you need to keep track whether or not the element is an animationframe, before canceling it. I wouldn't push the animationframe to that animationId array to begin with. That literally has no benefit. Instead you could do something like:

```
var rafId = 0;

var step  = function (){
    rafId = animate(step);
    update ();
    render ();
}

function reset (){
    cancelAnimationFrame(rafId);
    allFood=[];
    animationId = [];
    init();
}
```